# How to setup .travis.yml to build projects in subfolder?

Tags: travis-ci

How to setup `.travis.yml` config to build and deploy project in folders inside my repository? Each folder is a separate project (a part of large project), each project using own language and heroku url.
Is it possible? Now I found only `script: - cd subfolder` but it will build a single project in `subfolder`, not many projects with different configurations.

Comment: Have you made headway on this issue?

Comment: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/3540

Comment: @AndrewBurnett, yes, I found a solution. I'll post if I be able to find it in commit history coz we don't use travic ci already